# Will the debiased output automatically replace my model's output or not?

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-openscale

I ran a tutorial and see 'De-biased' output. I am not sure if that output is being sent to my application instead of my model's output. If it is not, is there a way to consume it?

Answer (score 0):

No the debiased output will not replace model output. Debias process will only add additional debiased_prediction, debiased_probability and debiased_decoded_target columns having debiased details.